# Sublimelinter & JSHint complaining about Facebook's Open Graph objects {og:url: "example.com"}

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, jshint, sublimelinter

I'm using JSHint and SublimeLinter with Sublime Text 3, but when using Facebooks API it doesnt like the object double `:` in the structure, eg. `{ og:url: 'example.com' }`

```
FB.api(
'me/objects/my-app:object',
'post',
{
    og:url: http://samples.ogp.me/12345678910,
    og:title: Sample Object,
    og:type: my-app:object,
    og:image: https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png,
    og:description: ,
    fb:app_id: 12345678910,
    place:location:latitude: Sample Location: Latitude,
    place:location:longitude: Sample Location: Longitude
},
    function(response) {
        // handle the response
    }
);
```

I know how to ignore certain variables and names in the .jshintrc file on the root of my project, but not sure how to stop it complaining about this structure.  I thought since the Facebook API is popular it's worth posting it here.

Comment: does that even work? because is surely is not proper javascript/json.

Comment: This is the example code generated by Facebook in the developer tools - so im guessing its correct syntax.  The example markup on the page that facebook looks for is `<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/path" />`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in quotes.
eg. `{ 'og:url': 'example.com' }`